# What connotation does, "to have something on someone" have?

Tags: expressions, connotation

Does "to have something on someone" connote wrongdoing, or is it innocuous?

Comment: It connotes potential blackmail. If `A` _has something on_ `B`, then `A` knows something that `B` would prefer that no one else knew. A past indiscretion or a present crime, for instance.

Comment: For context, the question is whether there is an implication of wrongdoing on the part of B, or whether the only implication of wrongdoing is on the part of A.

In the event that a third party, C, inquires with B as to whether A has something on him or her, is B justified in feeling insulted?

Answer (score 1):

to **have something on someone**  [YourDictionary.com](http://www.yourdictionary.com/have-something-on-someone)

> you know some fact or secret, or that you have some specific skill or
>   position, that gives you power over another person.

An example of **having something on someone** is knowing your friend is has 'crush' on X, and you threaten to tell X of this if your friend does/ does not do Y.